# Multi-Device Hybrid Apps - Google Map

Tags: multi-device-hybrid-apps

I want integrate a google map inside Multi-Device Hybrid Apps, I am following the example:

[Loading Google Maps in Cordova the Right Way](http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2014/08/13/loading-google-maps-in-cordova-the-right-way/comment-page-1/#comment-758)

this works, but the ripper emulator doesn't show me the map.

The Visual Studio has a "DOM explorer" tab and I can see others div inside the div with id=”map”, I think the map is inside.

The html and and .js code:

```js
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    //document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );
        
        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
        loadMapsApi();
    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
        loadMapsApi();
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
        loadMapsApi();
    };

    function loadMapsApi() {
        //if (navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE || google.maps) {
        if (navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE) {
            return;
        }
        $.getScript('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XX&sensor=true&callback=onMapsApiLoaded');
    }


    global.onMapsApiLoaded = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        //var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {});
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    };

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

} )(window);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>BlankCordovaApp1</title>

    <!-- BlankCordovaApp1 references -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, your application is ready!</p>

    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Somebody know why the emulator doesn't show the map?

regards

Comment: Please post your code. Does your `map` element have any height set? It might just be 0px tall. Try giving it a `height` in CSS?

Comment: I implement this example [Bing Maps in a hybrid app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387648/bing-maps-in-a-hybrid-app) work perfect I can see Bing Map, Why can I see Bing Map but not Google Map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you replace `API_KEY` in the maps URL with your own API key. Otherwise Google will block the loading of the map.

Also make sure you include the "connection" plugin, otherwise `navigator.connection` will be undefined.

I also had a typo in my example code here:

```
    if (navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE || google.maps) {
```

I was using `google.maps` without checking to see that `google` existed first.
The corrected code (also corrected in my blog post) would be:

```
    if (navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE || (global.google !== undefined && global.google.maps)) {
```

And finally, [here is a working example](https://github.com/rally25rs/cordova-google-maps-sample/).

Comment: In case someone would come across, In Cordova, I would also like to add to make sure  that the correct link to the Google maps API was used, and was in Cordova's whitelisted links. It got me when the url I was loading was on http, and the whitelisted ones is on https

Comment: Where that `Connection.NONE` come from? In my emulator it throws error `Connection is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an alternative answer. You could just predownload the script via bower ->

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "moduleType": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "stomp-websocket": "~2.3.4",
    "sockjs-client": "~1.0.3",
    "google-maps": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this with Ionic and I still get error on loading when I try to load a google map.